# Why/how do objects not have an init method?

Tags: java, object, methods, init

This is probably a simple OOP question, I'm kind of new in Java, so I was wondering why objects do not have an init method, and if objects don't then where is it used and why?

Comment: They have a constructor. Is this a homework question? You word it like one.

Comment: You need to improve the way you ask your questions in order to be helped. Try reading http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: It was derived from a homework question so which I already knew the answer to, I just wanted to know why/how so i could better understand the concept.

Comment: @user1629075 - That is not the point.  Francisco is not talking about what you asked about, or why you asked.  He is talking about how you wrote the question.  (For a start, it is only marginally intelligible.)

Comment: I was replying to Michael Berkowski, not Francisco.  As for Francisco's comment, I will utilize the link given to understand how to better ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you have constructors to initialize the instance.  It wouldn't be a bad pattern to introduce your own init-like method for an existing instance - post-construction - if you're creating a framework though, as there are safer ways to access members post-construction rather than during construction.

Comment: `init()` methods are a terrible anti-pattern!

Comment: init() methods aren't necessarily an anti-pattern if there's no choice but to handle initialization exceptions outside the constructor, which can happen sometimes.  Properly controlled and handled mid-tier it isn't such a bad thing.  I'd rather validate the proper construction of an object when all member objects have attempted to be constructed rather than rely on uninitialized or semi-initialized member objects.  Given a simple class with natives and riskless members, naturally I wouldn't do it, but sometimes that doesn't work out as planned.

Comment: In fact, if `init()` needs to start a thread or publish `this` to another thread, then it's not just a good pattern, it's required. You should never leak `this` to another thread from a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Objects have constructors which initializes it.  No init method though.